# Merging with two different objects without slit

Tags: mesh

I was merging with two different objects, but I couldn't erase a slit which were made up when merging with two different objects.
How can I erase this?[image]

Comment: Hello have you merged the meshes? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/